# How can I implement AND, OR and XOR logic using perceptrons in C#?

Tags: c#, neural-network, perceptron

I am learning neural networks basics.

How can I implement AND, OR and XOR logic using perceptrons in C#?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the SNNS and JNNS:

http://www.ra.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/SNNS/

http://www.ra.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/software/JavaNNS/welcome_e.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check my article on Perceptron (Artificial Neural Network) where I tried to provide an intuitive example with detail explanation.

"An Intuitive Example of Artificial Neural Network (Perceptron) Detecting Cars / Pedestrians from a Self-driven Car"

https://www.spicelogic.com/Journal/Perceptron-Artificial-Neural-Networks-10

[[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15e10.jpg)](https://www.spicelogic.com/Journal/Perceptron-Artificial-Neural-Networks-10)